# importing csv with psql \copy, modify data as it comes

Tags: postgresql, csv, psql

I frequently need to import a csv into postgres and usually use the `\copy` command from `psql`. It usually looks something like this

```
\copy tbl FROM import.csv CSV
```

I have two common problems which I feel might have a similar answer.

1. parsing date strings as they come in into a `TIMESTAMP` field
2. empty strings in `INTEGER` fields causing errors

In both cases there is minor modification that needs to be done, but my current solution is to create loading tables with all fields as type `VARCHAR`, then creating another table with the correct schema. I then use `\copy` and

```
CREATE TABLE loading_tbl (
    datefield VARCHAR,
    integerfield VARCHAR
);    

CREATE TABLE tbl (
    datefield TIMESTAMP,
    integerfield INTEGER
);

\copy loading_tbl FROM import.csv CSV

INSERT INTO tbl (datefield, integerfield)
SELECT
    to_timestamp(datefield, 'YYYY-Mon, DAY HH24:MI a.m'),
    integerfield::INTEGER
FROM loading_tbl;

DROP TABLE loading_tbl;
```

Is this the best method or is there a simpler way? It is kind of a pain to create two tables especially as the number of fields increases.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a scripting language to do the *ETL*. It may be easier to reason about and/or have less overhead, depending on your exact needs.

For example, you could use *Python*'s *csv* and *psycopg2* modules to interact with the *CSV* file and *Postgres* database, respectively, performing any *ETL* that's necessary. *psycopg2* will in general handle the timestamp string to actual *Postgres* timestamp conversion for you (assuming it's a recognized timestamp string, of which there are a variety of types).

For cases where there are fields in the *CSV* which are integers in *Postgres* but empty strings in the *CSV*, in the *Python* script, you can check for empty-string values and assign them to be *NULL* in *Postgres* instead.

I have used *Python* to do something like this very recently with good results. The biggest win over the solution you have in the question is probably the lack of needing transitional tables, since the *ETL* can be done in the script and then sent into *Postgres* via *psycopg2*.

If your *ETL* needs are modest, i.e. limited to the example you provided above, it may be worth sticking with pure *SQL*. One enhancement to that would be to use a `temp table` (for `loading_tbl`) instead of a regular table. That way you wouldn't need to be concerned about dropping it after *ETL*'ing the data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems like a step backward introducing a scripting language in order to ease a simple import. Using something like python would allow much more flexibility in working with types though. Perhaps the best solution would be write a general purpose command out of something like python that handles these cases by default if there is not a simpler solution.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Perhaps you should focus on the second option I listed, the use of `temp table`s. That should simplify things somewhat, in terms of not needing to worry about cleaning up the table after. If your ETL cases are what you listed above, using `temp table`s seems feasible. If they get more involved, then you may want to consider introducing a scripting language, or at least *PL/pgSQL*.